# On click select the optgroup in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<optgroup label="Food">
```

How can i do so when you press this link

```
<a class='clickMe' id='Food'>Show </a>
```

It should select the first `<option>` in the `optgroup`, that has the optgroup label "Food" (taken from the 'id' attribute in the link)

```
$('.clickMe').live('click', function(){
var label = $(this).attr('id');

// How can i select the first option from the optgroup label here?

});
```

Maybe if it helps, the select has name="product[][category]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//bind a click event handler to any elements that have the `.clickMe` class
$('.clickMe').live('click', function(){

    //change the value of the select input to the first option in the optgroup that has a label that is equal to the id of the link clicked
    $('select').val($('optgroup[label="' + this.id + '"]').children('option:first').val());
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/LqmJG/

Here's a quick break-down of the magic above:

- `$('optgroup[label="' + this.id + '"]')`: selects the option group with the label that matches the id of the link clicked.
- `.children('option:first').val()`: selects the first option (which is a child of the already selected optgroup tag) and gets its value.
- Both of these lines above are used to get the value of the first option in the selected optgroup, and then that value is used to set the value of the `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
var opt = $("select > optgroup[label=Food] > option:first");
```

Comment: You'd have to add single quotes to the label selector `$("select > optgroup[label='German Cars'] > option:first")` as the label name has a a space in it. http://jsfiddle.net/9eXrz/1/. I think you'd need to do the same as your label contains square brackets.